# How to mimic Guice's MapBinder using Windsor?

Tags: c#, java, castle-windsor, guice

The Guice IoC container provides MapBinder, which is often useful.
We're also using Windsor v3.0 in .NET.
Given the following slightly contrived example, can anybody suggest how Windsor could be used in the same way?

```
enum Format {
    Xml,
    Json
}
interface Formatter {
    String format(Object o);
}
class XmlFormatter implements Formatter {
    @Override
    public String format(Object o) {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
class JsonFormatter implements Formatter {
    @Override
    public String format(Object o) {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
class FormattersModule extends AbstractModule {
    @Override
    protected void configure() {
        MapBinder<Format, Formatter> formattersMapBinder
                = MapBinder.newMapBinder(
                        binder(), Format.class, Formatter.class);
        formattersMapBinder.addBinding(Format.Xml).to(XmlFormatter.class);
        formattersMapBinder.addBinding(Format.Json).to(JsonFormatter.class);
    }
}
class FormattersClient {
    private final Map<Format, Formatter> formatters;
    @Inject
    FormattersClient(Map<Format, Formatter> formatters) {
        this.formatters = formatters;
    }
    public void Format(Format format, Object o) {
        String s = formatters.get(format).format(o);
        // ... do something with s ...
    }
}
public class Main {
    private static Injector injector;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        injector = Guice.createInjector(new FormattersModule());
        FormattersClient formattersClient
                = injector.getInstance(FormattersClient.class);
        formattersClient.Format(Format.Json, new String("Foo"));
        formattersClient.Format(Format.Xml, new String("Foo"));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this example is quite straightfoward, if you're happy to use a string value for the key.

```
class FormattersInstaller : IWindsorInstaller
{
    public void Install(IWindsorContainer container, IConfigurationStore store)
    {
        container.Register(
            Component
                .For<IFormatter>()
                .ImplementedBy<XmlFormatter>()
                .Named(Format.Xml.ToString()));
        container.Register(
            Component
                .For<IFormatter>()
                .ImplementedBy<JsonFormatter>()
                .Named(Format.Json.ToString()));
    }
}
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var container = new WindsorContainer();
        container.Install(new FormattersInstaller());
        var xmlFormatter = container.Resolve<IFormatter>(Format.Xml.ToString());
        var jsonFormatter = container.Resolve<IFormatter>(Format.Json.ToString());
        // use the formatters...
    }
}
```